# Using different size coil for boost circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, boost, switching

I have an iPhone 6 with no backlight. Figured out it's the coil. The coil is rated at 15UH .72A 0.9ohm

I didn't have a replacement so out of curiosity I used a random coil off a donor board part of another circuit, but the specifications are different at 2.2UH 1.2A .15ohm

It worked and I got backlight again. Can even adjust brightness.

But I'm curious how this will effect the circuit in the long run. Will it make the switching ic work harder? Will the coil burn out?

Comment: Inductors aren't specified in Farads...

Comment: Aren't coils? My question says coils and that's what they're called in circuit

Comment: The unit of inductance is the [Henry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_(unit)). Assuming 15uH vs. 2.2uH, yes, the IC might be working harder, the inductor may be saturating, and there may be severe ripple on the backlight supply (which may make the backlight die sooner, or kill the caps with high ripple current). But it's hard to say what will happen without a more in-depth understanding of the circuit.

Comment: Yes UH typo on my end. It's a boost circuit taking 3.8v up to 20v. So you're saying the smaller coil will create more current and the current being filtered through the caps could cause them to die out?

Comment: A lower inductance _may_ result in higher ripple, which _may_ stress the caps and/or backlight. But I don't know for certain. Why not replace it with the correct part?

Comment: They're hard to find. Only found them on eBay from china. Know anywhere I can find those specs in smd size? Plus I wanted to verify it was the coil and not the ic. I'm curious how lower inductance may result in higher ripple. Is it because of the switching being more frequent?

Comment: [Here's a whole bunch of potential replacements](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/inductors-coils-chokes/fixed-inductors/71?k=&pkeyword=&pv66=1787&pv66=1718&pv66=1767&pv66=580&pv66=1752&pv66=1762&pv66=1439&pv66=2828&pv66=2630&pv66=557&pv66=2736&pv66=1778&pv66=1789&pv66=1363&pv66=2449&pv66=1774&pv66=1866&pv66=1730&pv66=63&pv66=1738&pv66=1776&pv66=1755&pv66=1433&pv66=851&pv66=3035&pv66=1775&pv66=1760&pv66=1732&pv66=2572&pv66=4&FV=ffe00047%2C4c000c&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500), maybe one of them is small enough

Comment: @user140123 No way of knowing the likely problems without lots more detail about the backlight circuit. The new coil has lower resistance ***and*** lower inductance. If the circuit uses fixed on-times, this means radically higher peak currents. But it is hard to know much at all without any detail.

Comment: To better understand the consequences of a lower inductance (and there may be other consequences that I have neglected), read up on the basics of boost converters, then read [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva763/snva763.pdf), for a start.

Comment: Would it help if I posted the schematic? Unfortunately no datasheet available for the ic as with most Apple circuits

Comment: For sure the ripple current will be higher. What we don't know is whether the higher ripple current will cause a problem. I would suggest finding something closer to the original value. Also, please edit the question (you are allowed to do that) to change uF to uH.

Comment: @mkeith Thanks fixed post. In finding something closer what's more crucial the UH, ohm, or amp rating?

Comment: Usually in boost converters like this one, the switching frequency is fixed. But the current ramp rate will be higher with a lower inductance. During the time the low-side switch is on, the current in the inductor ramps up linearly with time. Since it ramps up faster, it will ramp to a higher point to maintain regulation in the output. And when it is off, the voltage will fall a bit more, since it will be off for a longer time. So more ripple.

Comment: Ideally, Ohms should be same or less, amps same or more, and uH just closer to the original.

Comment: @uint128_t Which one would be the best option? All of them have different values from original and I'm not sure which would be ok to use

Comment: What mkeith said. If the DCR is equal or less, current is equal or more, and the inductance is the same, then select on which package best fits your application. And after that, go with the cheapest in stock. That's the beauty of parametric tables

Comment: @uint128_t I'm not sure what package/size the original is. Anyway to determine? There's no data on it anywhere

Comment: Got a pair of calipers? Measuring it might be a good start. Or maybe you can find a service manual?

Comment: Sounds reasonable, yes